# Unexpected end of JSON input when trying to authorize my sandbox from vscode

Tags: json, salesforcedx-cli, sandbox, vs-code, authorization

I am trying to authorize my sandbox org from vs code > After logging in with  my credentials, I keep on seeing this output from the browser which I Quoted below

"Unexpected end of JSON input

This is most likely not an error with the Salesforce CLI. Please ensure all information is accurate and try again"

[image]

Attempted Solutions:

1. Tried logging in from diffrent Browsers
2. Yes i am logging in from url that has https://xxx-nzahorg-zxc--cscdev.my.salesforce.com    - mydomian

It would be very helpful for me when someone solved this issue !

Answer (score 0):

Just to verify I would do this:

- Log in from test.salesforce.com.
- Delete expired keys (`sfdx force:org:list –clean`)
- Delete entries for that org in the  ~/.sfdx files